# Set cookies for one page only, not send back to server if user browse other page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Could cookies only set/get for one page only?

If I browse other page on the same root domain with that page, the cookies are not sent to server. Or are just not sent at all but still can access through jQuery cookie plugin.
I mean the cookies are only on client side, it will be very good to not send them to server.

My case is: On every page I need to store some cookies in browser and they differ depending on URL of page.

So if user browsed about 30 pages, browser will have 30 cookies and all of them will be sent to server when browsing any page.
That is not good anyway.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this. I would not recommend `setting a cookie for only one page and destroying it when you leave the page`, but instead, writing conditional statements into new parameters and identifying unique pieces of the page, such as the hash value or url, and appending data to the relative url or hash in the cookie.

Comment: thank for answer you know cookies need to be keep for long as they can, ( not one time session ). For second advice would you give any example javasripts? would be very helpfull. My purpose are: if the user comeback to brow that page again.. i could detect them for other actions..

Answer (score 3):

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain);
```

You might want to set the `$path` argument. See the [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) reference.

Comment: my urls at root domain. I think the cookies effect to all other page same root domain.. Are you mean I can set the path is actual url of page ? can I

Comment: here my url example: /modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=399620 ( it not type of folder or / . Do you think it work ?

Comment: There's also a [wonderful jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) that will do this for you. Basically the exact same thing, but figured I'd leave it here for others to peak at.

Comment: BinhNguyen: it won't work for your URL. If you really need page-specific cookie, try to use pretty URL for your site. Something like: `/modules/news/article/12345`.

Comment: to Ohgodwhy actualy i'm using it for creating cookies , but as I told.. cookies created in same root will be all send to server header.. what is not good.. 
@bsdnoobz My site been long, if doing new type of url will very hard job.. thanks for advices