# Prevent cookie from getting other pages?

Tags: php, security, cookies

I don't want to allow getting cookie from other page ! I have been searched on internet but not really found or may be I don't know how to mention that case .How can I manage that ! I want to get null in `test2.php` but get cookie in `test.php` ?

**test.php**

```
<?php
setcookie("acc_id", "23A", time() + 3600, '/');
header("test.php");
var_dump($_COOKIE);　// 'acc_id' => string '23A' (length=3)
?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE); // 'acc_id' => string '23A' (length=3)
```

Comment: ...so then don't call `$_COOKIE` in `test2.php`? Why do you not want it to carry across? That's killing what `_COOKIE`'s are designed for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cookies for one page only, not send back to server if user browse other page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763466/set-cookies-for-one-page-only-not-send-back-to-server-if-user-browse-other-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$path` parameter in the **setcookie** syntax.

`setcookie("acc_id", "23A", time() + 3600, '/test.php');`

Now if you try `print_r($_COOKIE['acc_id']);` from your test2.php, it will show you *Undefined Index*, which means the cookie is not set for that page.

[image: I have named the page as text.php in my environment.]